# Alter SQL Server Column in PDO

Tags: mysql, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to make an existing ID column in a SQL Server 
database AUTO_INCREMENT. I do not have access to the GUI.

I am trying this query.

```
$stmt = $this->conn()->prepare('ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN ID int NOT NULL auto_increment');
if($stmt->execute()){

}else{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

This gives the following error     `[2] => Incorrect syntax near 'auto_increment'. [20018] (severity 5) [(null)]`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I also tried "ALTER TABLE myTable CHANGE ID ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT", but it does not like CHANGE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that code certainly won't work on SQL Server where you can't alter table to add an identity functionality to a field after the table is created.

And it wouldn't work even if it could because Identity is what you use on SQL Server no autoincrement.

You need to add the identity as a separate column or do what SSMS does and create a new table with the identity, move the data and then drop the old table and rename the new one.

I can't speak for how to do it in mysql.

Incidentally ID is a horrible name for a PK field. Please use tablenameID. You will avoid alot of accidental bad joins and make reporting much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the input, seems like working with SQL Server is a bit more of a hassle.

Comment: @mike , for some things (including this one) yes, for others, no. Mostly it's just getting used to something that doesn't work the way something else you know works.